# Wpf Treeview issue

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xpath, treeview

How would i display the below XML to a WPF TreeView and it must display as follows

Category Name (Easy Puzzle)

- Puzzle Name (#1)

Category Name (Medium Puzzle)

- Puzzle Name (#1)

Category Name (Hard Puzzle)

- Puzzle Name (#1)

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SudokuLibrary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Puzzles>
    <SudokuPuzzle>
      <Category>Easy Puzzle</Category>
      <Name>#1</Name>
      <Rank>3</Rank>
      <Format>
        <string>6,0,0,5,0,4,7,0,0</string>
        <string>4,9,5,0,0,8,3,6,0</string>
        <string>1,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0</string>
        <string>0,5,0,0,0,1,4,2,8</string>
        <string>0,0,0,2,0,9,0,0,0</string>
        <string>3,2,1,8,0,0,0,5,0</string>
        <string>0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,3</string>
        <string>0,1,3,6,0,0,8,7,4</string>
        <string>0,0,8,1,0,3,0,0,2</string>
      </Format>
      <Solution>
        <string>6,3,2,5,1,4,7,8,9</string>
        <string>4,9,5,7,2,8,3,6,1</string>
        <string>1,8,7,9,3,6,2,4,5</string>
        <string>7,5,9,3,6,1,4,2,8</string>
        <string>8,6,4,2,5,9,1,3,7</string>
        <string>3,2,1,8,4,7,9,5,6</string>
        <string>9,7,6,4,8,2,5,1,3</string>
        <string>2,1,3,6,9,5,8,7,4</string>
        <string>5,4,8,1,7,3,6,9,2</string>
      </Solution>
      <SaveState>
        <string>6,0,0,5,0,4,7,0,0</string>
        <string>4,9,5,0,0,8,3,6,0</string>
        <string>1,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0</string>
        <string>0,5,0,0,0,1,4,2,8</string>
        <string>0,0,0,2,0,9,0,0,0</string>
        <string>3,2,1,8,0,0,0,5,0</string>
        <string>0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,3</string>
        <string>0,1,3,6,0,0,8,7,4</string>
        <string>0,0,8,1,0,3,0,0,2</string>
      </SaveState>
    </SudokuPuzzle>
    <SudokuPuzzle>
     **...**
    </SudokuPuzzle>
  </Puzzles>
</SudokuLibrary>
```

**I tried the following below**

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmldata" Source="Data/SudokuLibrary.xml" XPath="/SudokuLibrary/Puzzles/SudokuPuzzle" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="xmldatatemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="{Binding XPath=Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**TreeView**

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource xmldata}">
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <TreeView 
     x:Name="PuzzleTreeView"
     Grid.Row="0" 
     Width="140" 
     Padding="3" 
     Margin="10"
     ItemsSource="{Binding}"
     SelectedItemChanged="PuzzleTreeView_SelectedItemChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
 public class PuzzleName
    {
     public String Name { get; set; }
     public string puzzle{ get; set; }

        } 

public class Puzzle
 {

 public String CategoryName { get; set; }
 public List<PuzzleName> Children { get; set; }

        public Puzzle(string Categoryname)
        {
            Children = new List<PuzzleName>();
        CategoryName= Categoryname;
        }
//read the xml file and create an object for the puzzle and load the puzzle name (#1) as its childern
}
```

In MVVM...

```
List<Puzzle> puzzleList = new List<Puzzle>
```

In View...

```
<TreeView 
     x:Name="PuzzleTreeView"
     Grid.Row="0" 
     Width="140" 
     Padding="3" 
     Margin="10"
     ItemsSource="{Binding puzzleList , Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
     SelectedItemChanged="PuzzleTreeView_SelectedItemChanged"/>
```

Comment: May i add you to my github project? so you can have a look i still cant get it right.

Comment: Can i have your github username my repository is private i can invite you as a contributer

Comment: Hi there can you still help i need your github username